# How to make last word uppercase in C#?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

How can I print by reading the names and surnames from the keyboard and making only the surname letters large?

```
string name;
Console.Write("Name and surname:");
name=Console.ReadLine();

int word= name.LastIndexOf(" ");
Console.WriteLine(name.Substring(word).ToUpper());
```

I could write on surname but I could not add name.Sorry my english..

Comment: assuming that the last name is always in the last just use the `var surname = name.split(' ')[1]` then use the `ToUpper()` on it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to ask the user for name first and than ask for the surname. It's always better to split this during entry rather then having to deal with this in the code?

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.Split()` to separate first and last name

```
Console.Write("Name and surname:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(name.Split().First().ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(name.Split().Last().ToUpper());
```

---

if you want to stay with `Substring()` this would be the approach

```
Console.Write("Name and surname:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
int word = name.LastIndexOf(" ");
Console.WriteLine(name.Substring(word+1).ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(name.Substring(0, word).ToUpper());
```

Comment: And how do you handle full names like _Wernher M. Von Braun_ ?

Comment: Thnx so usefull (:

Comment: @Steve that was not part of the question

Comment: But I could assume that names like that exists and, still assuming, if the name is the first word.....

Comment: there is no trivial answer for that. Parsing academic degrees or peerage, recognition of a second/third first name and so on

Comment: Yes, the second step I'm working on is if the user enters two names

Answer (score 1):

**I solve my problem.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;/*Add this library for ToTitleCase*/

namespace String_denemeler
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ToTitleCase(string Text)/*And Add this for ToTitleCase*/
        {
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Text);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            Console.Write("Name&Surname:");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            name= ToTitleCase(name);

            int index = name.LastIndexOf(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(name.Substring(0, index) + name.Substring(index).ToUpper());

        }
    }
}
```